# Laravel DB Query WHERE date greater than not working with JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

### Background

I have written a SQL query that works perfectly for my needs, and I am trying to add it to a queued job in Laravel. Instead of using Eloquent models I wanted to go with DB Query to ensure better performance as there will ultimately be many joins and conditions. I am having a problem with the `where` clause when checking a date, but it works perfectly fine when running in SQL. I have stripped out additional pieces of this query to only include what is necessary for debugging this issue.

### Code

The original SQL:

```sql
SELECT `messages`.`created_at`, `participants`.`last_read`
FROM `messages` 
LEFT JOIN `participants` ON `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` AND `messages`.`user_id` != `participants`.`user_id` 
WHERE `messages`.`created_at` > `participants`.`last_read`;
```

When I run this directly in SQL, I see 2 results, which is expected with my current data.

| created_at | last_read |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-26 19:02:53 | 2021-03-23 19:31:30 |
| 2021-03-26 19:02:58 | 2021-03-23 19:31:30 |

This is how I have written it in Laravel:

```php
$query = DB::table('messages')
    ->leftJoin('participants', function ($join) {
        $join->on('messages.thread_id', '=', 'participants.thread_id')
            ->on('messages.user_id', '!=', 'participants.user_id');
    })
    ->select('messages.created_at as message_date', 'participants.last_read as last_read')
    ->where('messages.created_at', '>', 'participants.last_read');
```

When I execute this, the results are empty.
I dumped the final SQL from the DB Query builder to make sure it's correct, and this is what it is:

```sql
select `messages`.`created_at` as `message_date`, `participants`.`last_read` as `last_read`
from `messages`
left join `participants`
on `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `messages`.`user_id` != `participants`.`user_id`
where `messages`.`created_at` > participants.last_read
```

And running that directly in SQL returns accurate results, as expected.

### Context

For context, here is the data structure and some of the data I'm working with.

**participants**

| id | thread_id | user_id | last_read | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at | last_notified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 8 | 178 | 2021-03-23 23:31:53 | 2021-03-23 22:16:48 | 2021-03-23 23:31:53 | NULL | NULL |

**messages**

| id | thread_id | user_id | body | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 159 | 3 | 177 | adfad | 2021-03-26 19:02:53 | 2021-03-26 19:02:53 | NULL |
| 160 | 3 | 177 | dadddda | 2021-03-26 19:02:58 | 2021-03-26 19:02:58 | NULL |

### The problem

It seems as though the DB query code is causing the columns with like names to be mixed up. Both tables have a column called `created_at`, but I only need that column from the `messages` table. My `SELECT` only asks for that column, specifying the correct table. But something in this DB Query join is causing it to get mixed up.

Playing with different joins, and removing the `where` clause, I realized that the dates aren't correct always. For example, here is the result when I use `leftJoin`

```json
{
  "message_date": "2021-03-23 00:30:42",
  "last_read": "2021-03-26 00:22:48"
},
{
  "message_date": "2021-03-23 00:31:25",
  "last_read": "2021-03-26 00:22:48"
}
```

Notice, the `message_date` and `last_read` values are reverse of what they were when running the SQL directly. So this must be the problem.

I changed to `rightJoin`, and the results are reversed:

```json
{
    "message_date": "2021-03-26 19:02:53",
    "last_read": "2021-03-23 19:31:30",
},
{
    "message_date": "2021-03-26 19:02:58",
    "last_read": "2021-03-23 19:31:30",
}
```

So that should work, right? I add the `where` clause back in, but still the results are empty.

I am guessing there is something I need to do to tell the query builder to handle these columns correctly, as they seem to be getting mixed up during the `where` and `select`. But I can't figure out how to clarify that. I have tried searching for others with this issue but I can't seem to find anything relevant.

### Already tried

I have already tried a few things with no change in results.

- Changing the order of the commands - like moving the `select()` to the beginning of the statement, things like this.
- Using `whereDate` instead of `where`. (Note - for performance I'd rather avoid this, but wanted to try just in case).
- Using `join`, `joinLeft`, and `joinRight`.
- Using `where` in the `on` clause instead of two `on`s. Like this

  ```php
  ->leftJoin('participants', function ($join) {
      $join->on('messages.thread_id', '=', 'participants.thread_id')
          ->where('messages.user_id', '!=', 'participants.user_id');
  })
  ```

Anyone have any guidance on things I can try? This *should* be such a simple task, and has turned into hours of trying to understand why it works in SQL and not Laravel's DB Query Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` function of the query builder will always assume the right hand side is a value and will use it in a prepared statement as a literal (in this case string). If you want to compare columns you need to use `whereColumn`:

```
$query = DB::table('messages')
    ->leftJoin('participants', function ($join) {
        $join->on('messages.thread_id', '=', 'participants.thread_id')
            ->on('messages.user_id', '!=', 'participants.user_id');
    })
    ->select('messages.created_at as message_date', 'participants.last_read as last_read')
    ->whereColumn('messages.created_at', '>', 'participants.last_read')->get();
```

Additional where clauses can be found in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Comment: Wow. Such a simple and elegant answer... This definitely fixed the problem. I don't know how, but I completely overlooked the `whereColumn` while poring over the docs. Thank you! Who know how much more time I would have wasted on this.
p.s.. I'll accept as soon as it lets me.